# Sumar valores de objetos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito sumar el tax_value de cada objeto con el mismo taxid, y que devuelva los objetos completos con el tax_value sumado:

```
const taxis = [
  {taxid : 1, tax_name: 'VAT', tax_value: 25},
  {taxid : 2, tax_name: 'Service Tax', tax_value: 20},
  {taxid : 1, tax_name: 'VAT', tax_value: 25},
  {taxid : 2, tax_name: 'Service Tax', tax_value: 75}
];
```

Necesito que quede así:

```
const result = [
  {taxid : 1, tax_name: 'VAT', tax_value: 50},
  {taxid : 2, tax_name: 'Service Tax', tax_value: 95},
];
```

Intente con reduce, pero no logro sacar el resultado. Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias.

EDIT: Logré hacerlo asi, pero me suena a que es muy rebuscado, habra alguna manera mas facil de hacerlo?

```
  const result = [];
  taxis.reduce(function(acc, value) {
  if (!acc[value.taxid]) {
  acc[value.taxid] = { Id: value.taxid, tax_name: value.tax_name, 
  tax_value: 0 };
  result.push(acc[value.taxid])
  }
  acc[value.taxid].tax_value += value.tax_value;
  return acc;
  }, {});
  
  console.log(result)
```

Comment: Que has intentado?, pon un ejemplo mínimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, aquí las preguntas que no muestran algún intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el [tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [ask].

Comment: agrega el código de `reduce` que has intentado para de ahí decirte cómo podría quedar.

Comment: Ya sumé mi intento, funciona, pero no se si será lo mejor. Me podran ayudar a optimizarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo con el método [**`findIndex()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), en donde te devolverá el índice que cumple con la función, en este caso la función será si los valores de **`taxis`** son iguales, si se cumplen, los valores de **`tax_value`** se sumarán, y si no se cumplen, retornará **`-1`** y entrará a otra condición. Veamos:

```js
const taxis = [
  { taxis: 1, tax_name: 'VAT', tax_value: 25 },
  { taxis: 2, tax_name: 'Service Tax', tax_value: 20 },
  { taxis: 1, tax_name: 'VAT', tax_value: 25 },
  { taxis: 2, tax_name: 'Service Tax', tax_value: 75 }
];

const result = [];

// recorremos todos los elementos de taxis[].
taxis.forEach(element => {
  // buscamos los indices del arreglo que cumpla con la función, en donde la función
  // evalua si las claves "taxis" son iguales.
  const objectItem = result.findIndex(object => object.taxis === element.taxis);
  if (objectItem === -1) {
    // si dicha función no se cumple, pushea el mismo objeto.
    result.push(element);
  } else {
    // y si se cumple su igualdad, se sumará los valores de tax_value.
    result[objectItem].tax_value += element.tax_value;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Gracias! funciona, no lo habia planteado asi. Lo unico que cambie fue que no se por que en tu ejemplo cambiaste los taxID por taxis jajaja

Comment: @EzequielDiaz Recuerda que si sirvió, puedes marcar la respuesta para que tu pregunta esté como respondida =). Pensé que querías decir `taxis` en vez de `taxid`... no lo había notado xd

Comment: Si muchisimas gracias! Soy nuevo aca. Donde puedo marcarla como respondida? =)

Comment: Al lado de mi respuesta hay un check, puedes marcarla y darle voto arriba, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Solución con [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const taxis = [
  { taxis: 1, tax_name: 'VAT', tax_value: 25 },
  { taxis: 2, tax_name: 'Service Tax', tax_value: 20 },
  { taxis: 1, tax_name: 'VAT', tax_value: 25 },
  { taxis: 2, tax_name: 'Service Tax', tax_value: 75 }
];


const result = taxis.reduce( (acc,item ) => {
  const obj = acc.find(o => o.taxis === item.taxis);
  if (obj) {
     obj.tax_value += item.tax_value;
  } else {
     acc.push(item);
  }
  return acc;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Ahora si lo tuyo es SQL, puedes ocupar [alasql](https://github.com/AlaSQL/alasql)

```js
const taxis = [
      { taxis: 1, tax_name: 'VAT', tax_value: 25 },
      { taxis: 2, tax_name: 'Service Tax', tax_value: 20 },
      { taxis: 1, tax_name: 'VAT', tax_value: 25 },
      { taxis: 2, tax_name: 'Service Tax', tax_value: 75 }
    ];
    
let res = alasql('SELECT taxis, tax_name, SUM(tax_value) AS tax_value FROM ? GROUP BY taxis,tax_name', [taxis]);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alasql@2"></script>
```

Comment: Lo de `alasql` me sorprendió =)

Comment: Yo no lo conocía tampoco, buen aporte ;)

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte! muy bueno.
Yo lo de SQL ni se lo que es jaja estoy aprendiendo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que llegué un poco tarde, pero aun así te dejo otra solución que usa `reduce` y `filter`. He escrito una funcion llamada `reduce_array` que recibe tu array de `taxis` como parámetro. La idea es que, una vez tengamos el objeto final con la suma de todos los `tax_value`, lo saquemos del arreglo (pues ya lo reducimos), y asi hasta que ya no tengamos ningun objeto en el arreglo original.

```js
const taxis = [
  { taxid: 1, tax_name: 'VAT', tax_value: 25 },
  { taxid: 2, tax_name: 'Service Tax', tax_value: 20 },
  { taxid: 1, tax_name: 'VAT', tax_value: 25 },
  { taxid: 2, tax_name: 'Service Tax', tax_value: 75 }
];

function reduce_array(taxis) {
  taxis_reduced = []
  while(taxis.length) {
    // taxi sera el objeto ya reducido.
    taxi = taxis.reduce( (previous, current) => {
      const {taxid, tax_name, tax_value} = previous
      if (taxid === current.taxid) {
        return { taxid, tax_name, 'tax_value': tax_value + current.tax_value }   
      }
      return previous
    })
    taxis_reduced.push(taxi)
    // Como ya reducimos el objeto, no nos interesa tenerlo mas en el array de taxis. 
    // Entonces lo sacamos.
    taxis = taxis.filter((t) => t.taxid !== taxi.taxid)
  }
  return taxis_reduced
}

taxis_reduced = reduce_array(taxis)
console.log(taxis_reduced)
```