# Sumar todas las llaves con que empiecen por letra

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
[
    {
        "PERSONA": "JUAN MINOR",

        "PDIMEX": 1, // Cantidad de pagos
        "DIMEX": 100, // Total de pagos

        "PMEXI": 0,
        "MEXI": null,

        "PMEXIQ": 0,
        "MEXIQ": null,

        "PVIVALIA": 0,
        "VIVALIA": null,

        "PVIVALIAQ": 0,
        "VIVALIAQ": null,
    }
]
```

Las llaves que empiezan por letra P es un tipo de dato INT el cúal significa "cantidad de pagos" las llaves que no empiezan por P también es tipo de dato INT puede ser NULL o contener un valor el cuál significa "total de pagos" ¿Cómo le puedo hacer para que se sumen las llaves de total de pagos?

Francamente no tengo ni la menor idea, estaba basándome en la [otra pregunta de stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/565031/sumar-valores-de-objetos-en-javascript), pero no le entiendo, también estaba pensando en que era algo como:

```
let sum = 0;
for (let key in objeto) {
    sum += objeto[key];
}
```

Y al objeto[key] agregarle una condición tipo .chartAt(0) != 'P', pero por consola me dice que no es valido

Comment: Sí y no. Sí, todo es un objeto. Pero no, eso específicamente es un arreglo, no un objeto.

Comment: Muy bien deja corrijo mi pregunta, ¿Pero hay una manera de lograr lo que necesito?

Comment: Casi todo lo que se te ocurra es posible. Hay algo que deberías aclarar. ¿Quieres sumar todas las propiedades de un mismo elemento? ¿O las que se llaman igual de todos los elementos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero podrías realizar una búsqueda con `filter()` para decir que solo queremos encontrar las claves que no comienzan con `P`, usando el método `startsWith()`. luego de obtener las claves, usamos el método `reduce()` para hacer la sumatoria de **solo los valores** que sean de tipo **numérico**, esto lo hacemos gracias al `typeof`, así ignoramos al `null` que hay en algunos valores, ejemplo:

```js
let obj = [
  {
    "PERSONA": "JUAN MINOR",

    "PDIMEX": 1, // Cantidad de pagos
    "DIMEX": 100, // Total de pagos

    "PMEXI": 0,
    "MEXI": null,

    "PMEXIQ": 0,
    "MEXIQ": null,

    "PVIVALIA": 0,
    "VIVALIA": null,

    "PVIVALIAQ": 0,
    "VIVALIAQ": null,
  }
]

let resultado = Object.entries(obj[0])
           .filter(([key]) => !key.startsWith("P"))
           .reduce((total, [key, value]) => typeof value === 'number' ? total + value : total, 0);

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Cómo lo recorrería o aplicaría dentro de un $.each(response, (index, valor) => {}, donde el response es de una petición AJAX que me regresa el array, deja agrego el código en la pregunta, al final

Comment: Intenta poniendo todo el código de la variable `resultado` dentro de `$.each()`,  y luego debajo pones `sumatoria += resultado;`, todo esto que vaya arriba de `console.log(sumatoria)`, me avisas...

Comment: Estaba revisando tu respuesta, aporta información valiosa. Sumas las cantidades tal como las solicito en mi pregunta sin embargo estuve haciendo las pruebas en mi código con más personas y solo suma lo de la primer persona y lo aplica a todas las N personas. También hice eso que me dices en tu comentario de arriba y aplica lo mismo "Suma la primer persona y aplica a todas" (Genere cambios a pregunta, espero que sean de utilidad)

Comment: Eso lo podrías hacer en otra pregunta... de lo contrario, mi respuesta ya no serviría...

Comment: Genere una nueva pregunta en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/578636/sumar-keys-de-array-con-condicional-que-comiencen-diferente-de-letra-p-con-jav espero haber sido más especifico con la pregunta, una disculpa si esta pregunta no es concisa, espero me puedas ayudar y muchas gracias por el apoyo e interes @Cris223511.dev

Comment: Si, entiendo, si gustas puedes marcar como verificada esta respuesta, ya que era totalmente correcta con la primera versión de tu pregunta. Por cierto, sería bueno si dejaras esta pregunta en su primera versión, para que en la otra pregunta que hagas no parezca un **duplicado**.